# load activeX from JS doesn't work on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to load an activeX from JS function. The below code works on IE9 but not on IE8:

```
 obj_to_load = document.createElement("object");
 obj_to_load.innerHTML = "<OBJECT CLASSID=\"CLSID:4EC...\" CODEBASE=\"http://192.168.1.12:8000/ax_vs8.CAB\" ID=\"ax_101\" name=\"ax_101\">";
 document.body.appendChild(obj_to_load);
 ax = document.all('ax_101');
```

An thoughts?
10xs,
Nir

Comment: You are creating an `OBJECT` tag and then appending another `OBJECT` tag to it. Is that your intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE won't let you create an `object` element with `document.createElement`. Instead, you'll have to do something like:

```
var obj = document.createElement("div");
obj.innerHTML = "<OBJECT CLASSID=\"CLSID:4EC...\" CODEBASE=\"http://192.168.1.12:8000/ax_vs8.CAB\" ID=\"ax_101\" name=\"ax_101\">";
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```